# grunt-contrib-watch does not work with eslint to watch only changed file sets

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-eslint

I can't seem to get ESLint to run only on changed files using grunt-contrib-watch.

I was able to do it with JSHint.

Any help to get ESLint doing the same would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to set this up the other day, so I'll post a possible solution.

Regardless of whether you're trying to use `grunt.config` or `<%= ... %>` templating to dynamically modify the config object (to share data between the tasks), your problem might be that `watch`, by default, [spawns child processes](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionsspawn) for the triggered tasks, making eslint run in a different context.

To get around this, **just use the `spawn:false` options flag while configuring `watch`.**

Basically, configure your tasks as such:

```
watch: {
  scripts: {
    files: ['**/*.js'],
    tasks: ['eslint'],
    options: {
      spawn: false, // !!!
    },
  },
},
eslint: {
  target: '<%= changedFiles %>'
}
```

Then attach an event handler to the watch event, setting `changedFiles`:

```
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath){
  grunt.config('changedFiles', filepath);
}
```

You can also modify `eslint.target` directly in the event handler, but having an attribute carry the changed files makes it available to any number of task that might use them.